# Ubuntu distro upgrade getting disrupted (17.10 to 18.04 LTS 'Bionic Beaver')

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04, update-manager, locale

I am currently using Ubuntu 17.10 and am trying to upgrade to the 18.04 LTS new version.

After clicking on the "Upgrade" option in the Software Updater I am presented with a release notes window which has another "Upgrade" option. After choosing it I am presented with a 'do-release upgrade' screen which disappears as soon as it finishes downloading/loading some files.

I have tried restarting my machine, running the Software manager through different means but to no avail.

Is there another way to upgrade to the newest distro version other than simply installing a new image file on my drive?

EDIT: getting the following output when trying to upgrade using `do-release-upgrade -d`

OUTPUT:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
ERROR:root:gedefaultlocale() failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 388, in get_lang
    (locale_s, encoding) = locale.getdefaultlocale()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 562, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 490, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL
ERROR:root:gedefaultlocale() failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 388, in get_lang
    (locale_s, encoding) = locale.getdefaultlocale()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 562, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 490, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL
ERROR:root:gedefaultlocale() failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 388, in get_lang
    (locale_s, encoding) = locale.getdefaultlocale()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 562, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 490, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL
ERROR:root:gedefaultlocale() failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 388, in get_lang
    (locale_s, encoding) = locale.getdefaultlocale()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 562, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 490, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't even offer me the option to upgrade that way, and simply states the the software is up to date...

Comment: Typed the command. Getting a lot of errors such as: "ERROR:root:gedefaultlocale() failed" , "ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL ERROR:root:gedefaultlocale() failed" and I have no idea what they mean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1646260) with the `en_IL` locale and Python. Probably your `/etc/default/locale` file includes this line:

```
LANG=en_IL
```

Edit that file and change the line to:

```
LANG=en_IL.UTF-8
```

At next login you'll hopefully be able to upgrade successfully.

Answer (score 4):

run this command  to solve this problem

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```